Youtube-based Post-apocalyptic series about a technology malfunction
This was a web series that was broadcast on Youtube. Basically there is some kind computer chip in the body which suddenly stops working, causing mass deaths among users.
The show was set in Italy, USA, India, Finland as I can remember. I know in India was a surrogate mother that survived and that there was an Italian lady who was important but I can't recall why. 
I recall that the first episode was set in a underground garage where people are stuck since if they went out into the signal, they would die.
